# Let's say that there is an object called "Book" in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, dataweave, mulesoft, soql

The records in the book object are such, that one book can be the parent of other books, and it isn't necessary that each book has a parent book.

Given ID of a book, how to find out whether that book has child elements or not using an SOQL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, `Book__c` custom object has a self-relationship. Let's say, the name of the field of this relation is `ParentBook__c`. You want to use the following `SOQL` in order to check if this `Book__c` record with `Id` `ID_BOOK_TO_CHECK` has any child:

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Book__c
WHERE ParentBook__c = ID_BOOK_TO_CHECK
LIMIT 2
```

If this `SOQL` query will return not empty `List`, that means this record is a parent. `LIMIT 2` in this example, because `LIMIT 1` returns a single record, and if no such record throws an exception.